# Apostrophe vs its html hexadecimal notation conflict

Tags: php, parsing

I'm writing a little class to minify JavaScript with PHP.  I have the following problematic code in my class:

```
private function test_opener($str, $i) {

        if(ord($str[$i]) === 34 or ord($str[$i]) === 39)
        {   
            if($this->_is_string_opened)
            {
                if($this->_string_opener === $str[$i] and ! $this->is_escaped($str, $i))
                {
                    $this->_is_string_opened = false;

                    $this->_string_opener = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->_is_string_opened = true;

                $this->_string_opener = $str[$i];
            }
        }
}
```

My class loops through each character in the file. The function above detects string opening/closing haracters (`'` and `"`).  `0x34` and `0x39` are the character codes for `"` and `'`, respectively. If one of these characters is detected, a `is_string_opened` will be flipped to `true` if this is the first character opening the strong, or `false` if the character closes the string.

Now, my code breaks when I try to minify the following JavaScript (which is taken from the source of Underscore.js):

```
var entityMap = {
    escape: {
      '&': '&amp;',
      '<': '&lt;',
      '>': '&gt;',
      '"': '&quot;',
      "'": '&#x27;' // Here be dragons
    }
  };
  entityMap.unescape = _.invert(entityMap.escape);
```

So what's append when the parser reach `'&#x27;'` : The first `'` switch the `_is_string_open` to `true`. `&#x27;`, which is the HTML hexadecimal entity notation for `'`, turn it off, and the last `'` turn it on again. So the rest of the code is interpreted as text until the next `'`, which is obviously messing the file parsing process.

I don't understand this PHP behavior. The character code of `&;#x27;` isn't even `39`, it's `38`. I ran the code on PHP 5.5.9. The encoding is UTF-8 and the content come directly from POST, but i try to add a `htmlentities()` to escape this kind of problematic character, nothing changed.

Edit : The data origin (a Controller getting post data)

```
$js = $_POST['javascript_content'] ?: null;

if($js) 
{
    $output_js = Jsmin::forge($js)
        ->min()
        ->join()
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: What does minifying JavaScript have to do with any of the code you've written?  And, why would you write something to minify JavaScript by yourself?  This is not an easy problem to solve, and certainly cannot be solved correctly without something that can actually parse JavaScript.

Comment: I know that, but i do it to progress, just for me, you see. It's just a little class to minify and merge js files. And for your first question, this code is a part of the - almost - working class and has its function, i don't really understand your remark, can you argue a bit more ?

Comment: What you are writing is for replacing HTML and/or XML entities.  What does that have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: The second code you're talking about come from underscore.js, and this is the javascript code my minifying class can't deal with. Apparently you read my post too quickly.

Comment: I read your post four times to try to figure out what you are doing.  I didn't read it too quickly, your question doesn't make much sense.  I've edited the top half of your question to make it more clear, but the bottom half still doesn't make sense to me so I only added code highlighting around the quotes, as it wasn't clear before whether you meant them as literals or not.  Show your code for a loop.  Provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Sounds like the PHP is not getting the string as we see it. I wonder if the `&#27;` is being interpreted by the web server before your script gets to it.

Comment: @Brad, i think he's trying to, among other things, eliminate unnecessary white space, so he has to be aware of what is quoted so as not to eliminate quoted white space.

Comment: #x27 is character 39. (2x16)+7=39

Comment: Well thanks for editing the post brad, my english is poor, maybe i'm not clear and i'm sorry for that. So the class remove line breaks, uneeded spaces and oneline / multilines comments in javascript files, to output a minified file. (And can also merge several files in one). But the problem above don't require to understand what the full class really do. The thing is : my method make no difference between `'` and `&#x27;`, and i want it to ignore them in my input string

Comment: @JonathanM, Yeah you got it. And if your hypothesis is true (and i think it is, because escaping string with `htmlentities()` has no effect), what can i do to avoir it ?

Comment: @AdamSantoro, can you show us where test_opener is called? I'd like to see where the value for $str is coming from. Is it passed to the server in a POST?